# @ViewChild: access grand-child methods

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, viewchild

I have three nested components, called `level0`, `level1` and `level2`, defined like so:

```
@Component({
selector: 'level2',
template: `<div>I am level 2</div>`,
})
export class Level2 {
  getName(){
    return "my name is 'TWO'";
  }
}
```

---

```
@Component({
selector: 'level1',
template: `<div>I am level 1<level2></level2></div>`,
directives: [Level2]
})
export class Level1 {
  getName(){
    return "my name is 'ONE'";
  }
}
```

---

```
@Component({
selector: 'level0',
template: `<div>I am level 0<level1></level1></div>`,
directives: [Level1,Level2]
})
export class App {
@ViewChild(Level1) level1:Level1;
@ViewChild(Level2) level2:Level2;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if(this.level1){var name1 = this.level1.getName();}
  if(this.level2){var name2 = this.level2.getName();}
  console.log("name1",name1);
  console.log("name2",name2);
  }
}
```

In the console, I expected to see:

```
name1 my name is 'ONE'
name2 my name is 'TWO'
```

But I see instead:

```
name1 my name is 'ONE'
name2 undefined
```

What am I missing? Why can't the `Level0` component access `Level2` through `@ViewChild`?

Is there a way to access the `Level2` methods in `Level0`?

---

**[Here is the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vx9NY1EhUlhBLRB6gude?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible.

The [ViewQueryMetadata API doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewQueryMetadata-class.html) says the following:

> Supports the same querying parameters as QueryMetadata, **except descendants**.

The [QueryMetadata API doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/QueryMetadata-class.html) has this descendants example:

> Configure whether query looks for direct children or all descendants of the querying element, by using the descendants parameter. It is set to false by default.
>
> *... code here not shown ...*
>
> When querying for items, the first container will see only a and b by default, but with `Query(TextDirective, {descendants: true})` it will see c too.

Comment: @Manube, I think you'll be disappointed.  I believe Query is deprecated in favor of ViewChild and ViewChildren.  And if Query is still around, I don't think it supports `descendants`.  (I tried playing around with it a bit in a Plunker before I answered this question, and I couldn't get it to work.)

Comment: Right, then I will try and think differently. As I wish to implement an app where a parent should know all its selected, nested descendants, I guess I will just keep the data in services and inject them in the parent

Comment: @MarkRajcok the links are broken, can you update your answer please?

Comment: @stackdave I believe the Query feature is now totally deprecated; you won't find any docs on it.  ViewChild and ContentChild have to be used, which don't have a descendants query ability, as the 2nd comment above mentions.

Answer (score 7):

It can be acheived if you use ViewChild at each level of your nested components, like this way:

```
// Level 2
@Component({
selector: 'level2',
template: `<div>I am level 2</div>`,
})
export class Level2 {
  getName(){
    return "my name is 'TWO'";
  }
}


// Level 1
@Component({
selector: 'level1',
template: `<div>I am level 1<level2></level2></div>`,
directives: [Level2]
})
export class Level1 {
  @ViewChild(Level2) level2:Level2;
  getName(){
    return "my name is 'ONE'";
  }

  // You need to add additional function that would be called from level 1
  calledFromLevel1() {
    return this.level2.getName();
  }
}


// Level 0
@Component({
selector: 'level0',
template: `<div>I am level 0<level1></level1></div>`,
directives: [Level1,Level2]
})
export class App {
@ViewChild(Level1) level1:Level1;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if(this.level1) {
    var name1 = this.level1.getName();
    var name2 = this.level1.calledFromLevel1();
  }
  console.log("name1",name1);
  console.log("name2",name2);
  }
}
```